# Javascript Dialog box appears in IE but not Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a Javascript function that opens up dialog box that works well in IE but in Chrome, it doesn't appears, please advice, thanks!:

**Javascript:**

```
function modalDialog() {

   window.Page_ClientValidate();


            if (window.Page_IsValid) {
                document.getElementById('dialog').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';

                $('#dialog_link').click(function() {
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');

                return false;
                });
            }

}
```

**Dialog box:**

```
<div id="dialog" class="white_content" title="Cam" >
   <tr><td>Some Info</td></tr>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">

        .white_content
        {
            display: none;
            background-image: url('../../Images/prompt_bg.jpg');
            position: absolute;
            top: 25%;
            left: 0%;
            padding: 0px;
            z-index: 1002;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: wrong use of <tr> & <td> tags.

Answer (score 1):

You have your

```
<tr><td>...</td></tr>
```

nested inside a div tag. Chrome might have a problem with that because its a pretty non-standard use of the document object model.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I can note right off that bat is your Html is invalid. `<tr><td>` can only be used in `<table>`. I also believe that you need to change `window.Page_IsValid` to

```
if (typeof(Page_Validators) != "undefined")
```

Correct me if i'm wrong. Cause I just might be.